# Redirect to subdomain unless query string is present (nginx)

Tags: nginx

I am trying to redirect specific subpages to a subdomain in this manner:

1. If a query string isn't present handle the redirect to the subdomain
2. If a specific query string is present, don't redirect

The following handles the redirect:

```
      if ($page = ""){
        return 301 https://subdomain.example.com/$1/;
      }
      try_files  $uri $uri/ index.php?args;
```

But, this does not work when I'm trying to exclude the query string:

```
      if ($page = ""){
        return 301 https://subdomain.example.com/$1/;
      }
      if ($is_args = ""){
        return 301 https://example.com$is_args$request_uri;
      }
      try_files  $uri $uri/ index.php?args;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In your $is_args condition you check if its empty. And if so you use an empty string? How does it make any sense?

Additionally try to change the order of your conditions. If there are no arguments, than your $page will be empty as well:

```
  if ($is_args = ""){
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
  }
  if ($page = ""){
    return 301 https://subdomain.example.com/$1/;
  }
  try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?args;
```